# get a string from text with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I get only the text inside `Material[amhere]`?

For example, from...

```
PROD_RULE0001:WARNING: Metric[amhere] exceeded the UPPER WARNING limit[80.0]
```

... I want only the `amhere`.

I tried:

```
var strg = "WARNING: Material[amhere] exceeded the UPPER WARNING limit[80.0]";
var testRE = strg.match("Material\[(.*)\]");
alert(testRE[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
strg.match(/Material\[(.*?)\]/);
```

The ? after the * makes it lazy, so the . does not capture everything afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

another way maybe you want to use;

```
var material="Material[";
var str="WARNING: Material[amhere] exceeded the UPPER WARNING limit[80.0]";
var n=str.indexOf(material);
var amhere=str.substring(n+material.length, str.length).split("]")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.*` expression is greedy and therefore eats its way into the closing `]` rather than matching *up to* it.

In addition to @Telémako's solution, another way is to make the expression more strict by saying "match anything except `]`. This will also solve the problem.

```
strg.match(/Material\[([^\]*)\]]/);
```